# DEPRECATION: Using the defaultContainer is no longer supported (top-level view)

Tags: ember.js

I have this view, which must be added to the `body` element (it is not in a `ContainerView`):

```
App.NotAForm = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'sample',
    tagName: 'span',
    alert_img: function(event) {
        console.log('event=%o', event);
        event.preventDefault();
        alert(App.myModel.get('myModel_src'));
    },
});
```

This is the original implementation, to instantiate the view:

```
aView = App.NotAForm.create();
aView.appendTo('body');
```

But this is throwing:

```
DEPRECATION: Using the defaultContainer is no longer supported. [defaultContainer#lookup] see: http://git.io/EKPpnA
```

I have taken a look at the migration paths suggested [here](https://gist.github.com/stefanpenner/5627411), but no idea what is the right solution in this case. I have tried the following:

```
aView = App.view.createChildView('App.NotAForm');
aView = App.View.createChildView('App.NotAForm');
aView = Ember.View.createChildView('App.NotAForm');
```

To no avail. What would be the right approach to solve this deprecation warning?

Comment: In which part of your app are you creating the view? Seems a little bit awkward to create and append it manually to the DOM.

Comment: Yep, I think that too, but I am working on an example provided by somebody else (the jsbin [is here](http://jsbin.com/ufosEYO/3))

Comment: Just remove the manual creation of the view and instead use the view helper.Place `{{view App.NotAForm}}` into the Handlebars template where you need it.

Comment: Yep, that works. I had to modified the action helper, with this: `{{action alert_img target="view"}}`. It seems actions can not be handled in views by default now. Please add your comment as answer, so that I can accept it (and upvote question if you feel like).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Currently you use this code** to append views manually to the DOM:

```
aView = App.NotAForm.create();
aView.appendTo('body');
```

Instead use the `{{view}}` helper to append the view in a Handlebars template of your choice:

```
{{view App.NotAForm}}
```